# Visualforce Email Template Error

Tags: visualforce, email-template, vf-email-template

I am trying to enable automatic Visualforce Email Template, but I get the following error message on Visualforce Email Template Edit page:

> Error occurred trying to load the template for preview: common.apex.runtime.impl.ExecutionException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject. Please try editing your markup to correct the problem.

My code is the following:

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="Israel Bonds Transaction Summary" recipientType="Contact" relatedToType="Order__c">
<messaging:htmlEmailBody >
    <head>
    <apex:styleSheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.transactionSummaryCSS)}"/>
    </head>
    <c:transactionSummary orderId="{!relatedTo.Id}"/>
</messaging:htmlEmailBody>

<messaging:attachment filename="{!relatedTo.Name}" renderAs="pdf">
    <apex:styleSheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.transactionSummaryCSS)}"/>
    <c:transactionSummary orderId="{!relatedTo.Id}"/>
</messaging:attachment>
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

How can I fix that problem?

Comment: Can you post your component and controller code? It seems that it fails during rendering of transactionSummary component

Comment: The following is how my VisualforceComponent starts:

<apex:component controller="TransactionSummary" access="global">
    <apex:attribute name="orderId" type="Id" description="Order ID" assignTo="{!orderId}"/>

[...]

</apex:component>